# Adding emphasis to a PGFPlots function

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I have a function plotted with PGFPlots, and I'd like to add some emphasis to some maximum values and to some minimum ones, like the image below. How can I achieve that? (Sorry if duplicated, but my English skills weren't good enough to let me find more information about it).

Fair warning: I'm new to PGFPlots so if you answer, please consider explaining what the code is doing so I can understand better.

Here's the code I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis x line=center, axis y line=center,
    xmin=-1.5,xmax=9.5,ymin=-20,ymax=50, xlabel = {$x$},ylabel = {$y$}, ticks=none] 

        \addplot[smooth,domain=-1.25:8] plot (\x,{(\x-4)*(\x-7)*(\x+1)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And here is the image that produces (left) and what I want to achieve (right) - I used LibreOffice Draw to add in the dashed lines and extra information.

[image: The code produces the image on the left]

Comment: If you don't mind manually placing the lines, you can use `\draw [dashed]
              (axis cs: 0,36) --
              (axis cs: 1,36) --
              (axis cs: 1,0);` just before the `\end{axis}` command. `axis cs:` tells pgfplots to use the coordinate system of the current axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AJN commented, you can use the coordinate system of the axes and draw lines between points using the regular tikz commands. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis x line=center, axis y line=center,
  xmin=-1.5,xmax=9.5,ymin=-20,ymax=50, 
  xlabel = {$x$},ylabel = {$y$}, ticks=none ] 

  \addplot[smooth,domain=-1.25:8] plot (\x,{(\x-4)*(\x-7)*(\x+1)});
  \draw [dashed] (0,36)  node[left] {$y_1$} -- (1,36) --
      (1,0) node[below] {$x_1$} ;
  \draw [dashed] (axis cs: 5.7,0)  node[above] {$x_0$} -- 
      (axis cs: 5.7,-15) -- (0,-15)  node[left] {$y_0$} ;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The figure:
[image]

Comment: I noticed that you added in the preamble: `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}`, and that turned out necessary for this to work... What does that do and why is it necessary? Also, would it be possible to add in those lines if I wasn't sure of where the maximums/minimums are? I mean, could `PGFPlots` calculate them in order to add in such emphasis?

Comment: As per the manual compat=1.13 will set the compatibility layer. It is needed to make sure the proper version is used for compiling the code. I added the lines looking at the values. Did not calculate them.